# Left Joining table with values in lookup table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables on SQL-Server. One containing clients, and one a client profile lookup table. So a bit like this (note that Fred doesn't have any values in the lookup table):

```
Table: Clients         Table: Profile
ID | Name  | Status            ClientID | Type | Value
-----------------------        -----------------------
 1 | John  | Current                  1 | x     | 1
 2 | Peter | Past                     1 | y     | 2
 3 | Fred  | Current                  2 | x     | 3
                                      2 | y     | 4
```

I then am trying to create a tmp table that needs to contain all current clients like this:

```
ID | Name  | TypeY
==================
 1 | John  | 2
 3 | Fred  |
```

My knowledge of SQL is limited, but I think I should be able to do this with a Left Join, so I tried this (#tmpClient is already created):

```
insert into #tmpClient
   select a.ID, a.Name, b.Value
   from Clients a
   left join Profile b
   on a.ID = b.ClientID
   where a.Status = 'Current' and b.Type = 'y'
```

However this will always miss Fred out of the temporary table. I am probably doing something very simple wrong, but as I said I am missing the SQL skills to work this one out. Please can someone help me with getting this query right.

Answer (score 2):

You have to move the predicate concerning the second table of the `LEFT JOIN` operation from `WHERE` to `ON` clause:

```
insert into #tmpClient
   select a.ID, a.Name, b.Value
   from Clients a
   left join Profile b
   on a.ID = b.ClientID and b.Type = 'y'
   where a.Status = 'Current'
```

Comment: Just tried that and it gives me the same results. Still no Fred. I think it has to do with the fact he does not appear in the Profile table and therefore there is no b.Type = 'y' for his ClientID.

Comment: @Kees This shouldn't be an issue since `b.Type = 'y'` predicate appears in the `ON` clause.

Comment: Finally worked it all out. The query puts the right results in the temp table, but the code that follows it doesn't process it properly. I seem to have been chasing after a non-existing error all afternoon. Thank you so much for your help.